# Can I use blender VSE as if it's power point?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'd like to write some text and animate it. I also would like to put some shapes like arrows, circles, rectangles, and lines. I might need to animate the shapes too. I know that the best software to do it is powerpoint but I'd like to use open source software so does blender VSE has the same efficiency as powerpoint?

Comment: There are opensource alternatives to powerpoint. However, Blender is not one of them. I have done a presentation using the opengl viewport. It involved some scripts and hardcoded cameras but wasn't very efficient.

Comment: @Leander Okay thank you so much for your comment

Comment: Have you considered [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/)? It has a module called "Impress" which offers similiar functionality to powerpoint. It's a free, open-source office suite, available for all platforms.

Comment: I have done this in Blender for small projects, mainly for the credits section but also for some labels. I found that setting an orthographic camera with a strong sun lamp pointing straight down allowed me to set the render samples very low and still get clear results. Also found duplicating the basic scene handy for keeping everything organised. To make text/basic objects appear and disappear, set the location off screen at one frame and on the next and key frame it, Blender with calculate the interpolation correctly.